# Encryption with alfresco-pdf-toolkit-1.0.0

Tags: alfresco

I installed alfresco-pdf-toolkit-1.0.0.amp, and I added rule to the space I want to my PDFs be encrypted, but when I try add PDF file, I get an error:

Please correct the errors below then click OK.
    Failed to create content due to error: For input string: "128 bit AES".

Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not telling us all,
Alfresco version. what encryption options you are trying to apply and whatsoever.

You should look here:
[PDF Toolkit Digital signatures](http://www.unorganizedmachines.com/site/software-and-technology/34-software-development/106-alfresco-pdf-toolkit-digital-signatures.html).
The article explains how you should use the encryption with the PDF Toolkit.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I use v.4.2.2 of Alfresco. I am trying to encrypt PDF documents by AES algorithm, witch is provided by this amp file. I look at the link, but it is for digital signatures, not for encryption.